# Response.AppendHeader() is broken

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I'm using

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "2; url=default.aspx")
```

To send users back to the home page after they log in or log out and it works. But, on the contact us page it fails and this is what it says:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /default.aspx, 2; url=default.aspx

The weird thing is this doesn't happen in debug, only on the live site. It looks like it's appending the header twice somehow... I don't know. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the contactus inside another folder like /contact/contactus.aspx? If it is, on the live site, try putting `url=../default.aspx` (relative path) and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: No, default.aspx and the contact form are in the same folder. And it works in debug...

Comment: Have you used something like FireBug to check the headers and make sure that the header is transmitted properly?

Comment: Ok, the weird thing is on the logout page, it shows the redirect in the header but the header doesn't appear on the contact page after submit, yet it still redirects to the error page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was. In my aspx I had

```
onclick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server"
```

You only need the runat="server" directive. The onclick directive was causing the event handler to fire twice.

Answer (score 0):

If the Contact page is not in the same path as Default.aspx, the relative path will not work. You will need to give it the absolute path like "../Default.aspx" if its one level down.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution is to replace:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "2; url=default.aspx");
```

with:

```
Response.Headers["Refresh"] = "2; url=default.aspx";
```

The cause of HTTP 404 errors is due to duplicate "Refresh" header in the HTTP Response-headers.  It doesn't affect IE but it does Chrome.

This is a tricky issue where you would understand this only when you see the HTTP Response-headers in browser's developer mode.

In ASP.NET if you are using `Server.Transfer` then even though the transfer is complete the page name in the address bar is not changed. For e.g. if you are transferring from `Default.aspx` to `Managers.aspx` then the address bar still says `Default.aspx`.  And when  `Response.AppendHeader` is on both `Default.aspx` and `Managers.aspx` pages then on transfer the headers gets added twice to `Default.aspx`.